# C++ try/catch not catching exception

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have the following try/catch:

```
try
{
    Player newPlayer = Database::newPlayer(atoi(arguments.at(1).c_str()), arguments.at(2));
}
catch (int e)
{
    cout << "Wrong parameters used.\n";
}
```

My goal is to be able to add a player, and if for some reason the arguments don't match, such as putting a non-integer for `arguments.at(1)` or not enough arguments, but in Visual Studio if I do this then the program crashes and Visual Studio says "unhandled exception, std::out_of_range at memory location." I want my program not to crash when this happens but simply say "Wrong parameters used" as it currently is in the catch statement.

Comment: You're catching an `int`. You know this right?

Comment: To catch everything, use `catch (...)`, but don't do that.

Comment: You need to catch std::out_of_range instead of int

Comment: Catch the `std::out_of_range` type instead of `int`.

Comment: I agree with the above: you're catching an int

Comment: I'd recommend [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) (or [`boost::lexical_cast`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html) if you're not up to C++11 yet) instead of `atoi()`. `atoi()` will not throw anything on an invalid integer, just return a 0.

Answer (score 7):

You need to be catching `std::out_of_range` not an `int`.

Answer (score 4):

You need to catch std::out_of_range instead of int

```
try
{
    Player newPlayer = Database::newPlayer(atoi(arguments.at(1).c_str()), arguments.at(2));
}
catch (std::out_of_range& e)
{
    cout << "Wrong parameters used.\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to catch the std::out_of_range exception, for example:

```
try
{
   //your throwing code
}
catch (std::out_of_range &e)
{
    cout << "Wrong parameters used.\n";
}
```

Also notice the catch using the reference (the & usage) instead of catching by value like you did with the int, to avoid any problem with object slicing and redundant copies.